# Is there a way to directly show a received push notification on Android without using Notification Builder to manually build it?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui, android-notifications

I have implemented push notifications on my .NET 7 MAUI application using Azure Push Notification Hub as a provider.

I am able to register my devices (both Android and iOS) on Azure and to let them receive the push notification from my backend application.

On iOS my notifications are directly getting on the banner without any further implementation on client side once they are sent.

On Android, though, despite I receive the notification in my push delegate, I can't see any banner unless I manually use `Notification.Builder` and I manually build all the details of the banner to be shown.

Is there a way I can have the notification banner automatically shown in Android as well?

In case this is not achievable, is there a nuget or something similar you would suggest to properly manage local notifications on both platforms?

I am trying to achieve a consistent and common behavior between Android and iOS.

Comment: This depends on the message type you send. On Android the system handles `notification` messages when the app is not active. In all other cases, the message is delivered to your app to display.